# Custom post type permalink structure

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I've browsed tons of Q/A on stackexchange, google, wordpress forums... but haven't found yet a definitive answer to what looks like to be a common issue since the introduction of custom post types.

I've set my permalinks structure from Wordpress admin permalink settings page as:

```
/%post_id%/%post_name%/
```

since this is a good practice to improve database performance

however, I noticed my custom post types (I have several in one configuration) still appear as:

```
%cpt_slug%/%post_name%/
```

while what I really want is

```
%cpt_slug%/%post_id%/%post_name%/
```

and actually would love if it could also work as

```
%cpt_slug%/%post_id%/%taxonomy%/%post_name%/
```

but as for now, I would like to get the post_id work in the cpt structure

how to achieve this?

there was a wordpress plugin but apparently it was withdrawn because had some issues (and anyway is no longer mantained)

Comment: >"since this is a good practice to improve database performance" Note that this will no longer be the case in WordPress 3.3 which is being released imminently. You can just use /%postname%/ without performance penalty.

Comment: oh yeah I actually just read that after posting, good

anyway from a SEO point of view it would be nice to have the %taxonomy% in the cpt permalink displayed

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function myrules(){
    add_rewrite_rule('^yourcptslughere/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?p=$matches[1]&taxonomy=$matches[2]&name=$matches[3]','top');
}
add_action('init','myrules');
```

Replace the '**yourcptslughere**' with what you wanted, and then add that to functions.php then flush your rewrite rules, and the final example you posted should work. I doubt it will be what `the_permalink()` returns however so you will have to construct the urls yourself, however they should be viewable at those URLs **e.g.:**

```
example.com/randomcptslug/123/exampletaxonomy/testpost
```

Comment: I think you can skip matching the name and taxonomy, when you are already looking up post via post_id. so `index.php?p=$matches[1]` will be enough.

Comment: Indeed! Although I put the whole thing in just encase

Answer (score 0):

WordPress are working on increasing the performance of Custom Permalink Structures which is supposed to be completed on the next update

Comment: ok, you mean 3.3? that would be awsome